# Consultas en tablas con relacion de muchos a muchos

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas entre si por una tercera tabla, mi pregunta es, ¿Como puedo obtener el resgistro de la primera tabla que tenga relacion con los registros de la segunda tabla?

primera tabla.

```
CREATE TABLE `profesor` (
  `CodProf` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombre` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `AP` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `AM` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `Calle` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `Numero` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `FechaN` date NOT NULL,
  `Sexo` char(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CodProf`)
);
```

segunda tabla.

```
CREATE TABLE `materia` (
  `CodMat` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombre` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `Descripcion` text NOT NULL,
  `CodCar` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CodMat`),
  KEY `CodCar` (`CodCar`),
  CONSTRAINT `materia_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CodCar`) REFERENCES `carrera` (`CodCar`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

tabla intermedia.

```
CREATE TABLE `pro_mat` (
  `CodProf` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `CodMat` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Cuatrimestre` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CodProf`,`CodMat`),
  KEY `CodMat` (`CodMat`),
  CONSTRAINT `pro_mat_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CodProf`) REFERENCES `profesor` (`CodProf`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `pro_mat_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`CodMat`) REFERENCES `materia` (`CodMat`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

en la tabla profesores tengo estos datos.
[image: Datos tabla profesor]

en la tabla materia tengo estos datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la tabla pro_mat que es la que relaciona a las dos tablas anteriores tengo esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero obtener es el nombre completo del profesor que da todas las materias osea.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no se me ocurre ninguna forma de obtener solo el nombre de ese profesor.

Comment: ya lo eh corregido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otra version que hace todo de una, sin importar la cantidad de materias, ya que las toma de la tabla materias...

```
Select p.nombre
from profesor p
where p.codprof in (
    select codprof
    from pro_mat
    group by codprof
    having count(codmat) = (select count(*) from materia)
    )
```

Lo que hace esto es seleccionar los nombres de profesores para aquellos que esten en la tabla intermedia y solo si figuran la cantidad de veces segun la cantidad de materias existentes.

Answer (score 0):

**OPCIÓN 1**

La consulta sería así:

```
SELECT profesor.Nombre,
       materia.Nombre
FROM profesor
INNER JOIN pro_mat ON profesor.CodProf = pro_mat.CodProf
INNER JOIN materia ON materia.CodMat = pro_mat.CodMat;
WHERE profesor.Nombre = "David";
```

Motivos:

- Seleccionamos las 2 columnas de las 2 tablas que alimentan a la tabla intermedia
- Hacemos el primer FROM desde la tabla `profesor`
- En le primer JOIN la unimos con la tabla intermedia que es pro_mat
- La primer igualación en el ON la hacemos con la llave primaria de la tabla profesor y que tiene su equivalente en llave foránea en la tabla pro_mat

El último punto anterior es el que repetimos para el segundo inner join

**OPCIÓN 2**

O considerando que se sabe que siempre son 3 materias podemos hacer un `HAVING` para filtrar si la llave foránea del profesor aparece ecactamente 3 veces

```
SELECT profesor.Nombre,
       materia.Nombre
FROM profesor
INNER JOIN pro_mat ON profesor.CodProf = pro_mat.CodProf
INNER JOIN materia ON materia.CodMat = pro_mat.CodMat
HAVING COUNT(pro_mat.CodProf) = 3;
```

Esta segunda opción considerando que:

> Si la cantidad de materias en total son 3, entonces aquel maestro que de todas las materias, entonces su llave primaria en la tabla intermedia debería aparecer un máximo de 3 veces.